# How to change base_url in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

From the beginning I have project name "A".
When I run my project I use this url : http://localhost:8080/A/

Then I want to change my base url from http://localhost:8080/A/ to http://localhost:8080/B/

What file I must reconfig to change my base url become http://localhost:8080/B/ ?

I read some article just change it in file org.eclipse.wst.common.component, but no effect.

Comment: That highly depends on the server you use.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry I dont get it what you mean, could you tell me?

Comment: Are you using an IDE, such as Eclipse, then set the context-path for that project and define the same method in controller as well.

Comment: How to change that URL depends on the server you use. It is different for tomcat, jetty, web logic etc. So without knowing which container you use it is hard to tell how to do it.

Comment: @M.Deinum i use tomcat

Comment: Add a `Context.xml` file in the `META-INF` directory. As explained [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html). IN that you can specify the url.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet mapping can be define in the file WEB-INF/web.xml. For example :

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or It can define in a full java based configuration. For example :

```
 // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
 ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
 dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
 dispatcher.addMapping("/");
```